# DTD validation issue

Tags: vb.net, dtd, xml

I'm using the following code to validate an XML file:

```
'DTD validation
        Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        Dim dtdDoc As String = ftpPath & "\" & dtdDocument

        AppendText(vbCrLf)

        Try
            doc.Load(fileName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            AppendText(ex.Message)
            ShowFailMessage()
        End Try

        Dim isXmlValid As Boolean = True
        Dim xmlValMsg As New StringBuilder()
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()

        doc.Save(sw)
        doc.Save(fileName)

        Dim stream As Stream = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)
        Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings()
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
        AddHandler settings.ValidationEventHandler, AddressOf ValidationCallBack
        Dim r As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings, "R:\ftproot\graphics\" & dtdDocument)

        While r.Read()
        End While

        r.Close()
        stream.Close()
        stream.Dispose()

Private Shared Sub ValidationCallBack(sender As Object, e As ValidationEventArgs)
    AppendText("DTD Validation Error: " & e.Message)
    isDTDValidated = False
End Sub
```

I am getting the following error from this validation code:

"The element 'MarketDate' has invalid child element 'Date'. List of possible elements expected: 'DateFormat'."

Here's the relevant XML:

```
<MarketDate>
      <MarketDateRole>01</MarketDateRole>
      <Date>20150202</Date>
    </MarketDate>
```

Here's what's in the DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT MarketDate (MarketDateRole,DateFormat,Date)>
```

So 'Date' is a valid child element. I am *guessing* it's not that Date is invalid but that DateFormat is missing. Am I correct with this assumption?

Comment: I think I just answered my own question. According to w3schools:

"When children are declared in a sequence separated by commas, the children must appear in the same sequence in the document."

Comment: I agree. Incidentally, most people have moved away from DTDs in favor of XSDs (those who haven't moved away from XML entirely).

Comment: Yep. But my instructions are to do DTD validation so nothing I can do about that.